# View pdf in JPanel

Tags: pdf, jpanel, pdfbox

How to view the pdf in JPanel using PDfBox??

I have the Source Code Like below.

```
   try {
        PDDocument inputPDF = PDDocument.load(FilePath);
        List<PDPage> AllPages = inputPDF.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        inputPDF.close();
        PDPage TestPage = (PDPage)AllPages.get(0);
        PDFPagePanel pdfPanel = new PDFPagePanel();
        pdfPanel.setPage(TestPage);
        pnlRiwayatStatus.add(pdfPanel);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
```

But thus source code NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: A `NoClassDefFoundError` in its message usually indicates which class definition is not found. Thus, please share the error message.

Comment: The Error Message like it

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

Comment: @AgusVirgaTendean if the answer helped get rid of the exception (and I bet it did), please click on the checkmark to make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The missing class is mentioned in a comment:

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
> ```

This shows that you don't have the Apache Commons Logging jar in your class path.

According to the [PDFBox web site](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/dependencies.html), though, it is a required dependency:

> #### Minimum Requirements
>
> PDFBox has the following basic dependencies:
>
> - Java 6
> - [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/)
>
> Commons Logging is a generic wrapper around different logging frameworks, so you’ll either need to also use a logging library like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) or let commons-logging fall back to the standard [java.util.logging API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html) included in the Java platform.

You should consider using [Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) for automatic dependency resolution.